# How to get consumer group offsets for partition in Golang Kafka 10

Tags: go, apache-kafka, shopify

Now that Golang Kafka library (sarama) is providing consumer group capability without any external library help with kafka 10. How can I get the current message offset being processed by a consumer group at any given time ?

Previously I used kazoo-go (https://github.com/wvanbergen/kazoo-go) to get my consumer group message offset as it is stored in Zookeeper. Now I use sarama-cluster (https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster), I am not sure which API to use to get my consumer group message offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also working with Sarama and Kafka to get offset of a topic.

You can get offset with following code.

```
    package main

    import (
     "gopkg.in/Shopify/sarama"
     "fmt"
    )

    func main(){
      client , err := sarama.Client([]string{"localhost:9092"},nil) // I am not giving any configuration
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
      lastoffset, err := client.GetOffset("topic-test",0,sarama.OffsetNewest)
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
      fmt.Println("Last Commited Offset ",lastoffset)
    }
```

Let me know if this is the answer you are looking for and if it is helpful.

Comment: This works. I figured there was a problem on my Kafka cluster side which caused not returning any data for this API call. Works now.

Comment: Does this return the offset of the last message produced for a partition, or the offset of the last message marked and committed by the consumer for a partition?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli The code returns the latest offset produced for a partition, NOT offset committed by consumer

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question. This just gets the latest offset for the given partition of a topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code to get the consumer group offset (i.e. the offset where the consumer group will start):

```golang
package main
    
    import (
        "context"
        "log"
        "strings"
    
        "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    )
    
    func main() {
        groupName := "testgrp"
        topic := "topic_name"
        offset, e := GetCGOffset(context.Background(), "localhost:9092", groupName, topic)
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatal(e)
        }
        log.Printf("Consumer group %s offset for topic %s is: %d", groupName, topic, offset)
    }
    
    type gcInfo struct {
        offset int64
    }
    
    func (g *gcInfo) Setup(sarama.ConsumerGroupSession) error {
        return nil
    }
    
    func (g *gcInfo) Cleanup(sarama.ConsumerGroupSession) error {
        return nil
    }
    
    func (g *gcInfo) ConsumeClaim(_ sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {
        g.offset = claim.InitialOffset()
        return nil
    }
    
    func GetCGOffset(ctx context.Context, brokers, groupName, topic string) (int64, error) {
        config := sarama.NewConfig()
        config.Consumer.Offsets.AutoCommit.Enable = false // we're not going to update the consumer group offsets
        client, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroup(strings.Split(brokers, ","), groupName, config)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        info := gcInfo{}
        if err := client.Consume(ctx, []string{topic}, &info); err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        return info.offset, nil
    }
```

Comment: if one needs last committed offset when processing, this works. if its auto commit then this is all you need. If one is using manual commit and processes next message before committing previous one, then save the  message offset of first message in a session (of each partition) to a store, and manually update store on each commit

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood the `consumerGroupSession` struct is using `PartitionOffsetManager` to [get next offset](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/83d633e6e4f71b402df5e9c53ad5c1c334b7065d/consumer_group.go#L662):

```golang
    if pom := s.offsets.findPOM(topic, partition); pom != nil {
        offset, _ = pom.NextOffset()
    }
```

Here is the documentation of [pom.NextOffset()](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/offset_manager.go#L429).

When a `consumerGroupSession` constructs a `consumerGroupClaim` struct via `newConsumerGroupClaim()` method, it passes offset, returned by `pom.NextOffset()`, as `offset` argument. You can access it later via `claim.InitialOffset()`. After you started consuming messages, you can use `message.Offset` of the currently processed message.

Unfortunately, `consumerGroupSession.offsets.findPOM()` can't be accessed from `ConsumerGroupHandler.ConsumeClaim(session sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim)` method, because it receives session as a `ConsumerGroupSession` **interface**, not as `consumerGroupSession` **struct**. So the offsets variable is private and not accessible.

Thus we can't really access `NextOffset()` method, which does precisely what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been doing work on this myself. As @boris-burkov mentioned you don't have access to the getPOM method, however, you can create a POM yourself and called NextOffset() to get the current consumer's actual offset:

```golang
offsetManager, _ := sarama.NewOffsetManagerFromClient(clientName, cl.Client)
offsetPartitionManager, _ := offsetManager.ManagePartition("test-topic", 0)
offsetPartitionManager.NextOffset()
```