# Get consumer group offset for all topics for all groups in kafka using go

Tags: go, apache-kafka

NOTE: **NOT A DUPLICATE OF** [How to get consumer group offsets for partition in Golang Kafka 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642689/how-to-get-consumer-group-offsets-for-partition-in-golang-kafka-10) does not answer my question, it's not even a working solution

I'm trying to write a function in go that queries kafka for all consumer group offsets for all topics.

To do that, I was hoping to read all the messages in `__consumer_offsets` topic and parse them.

However, in all the kakfa go libraries I looked through, I could not find a way to just *read* all the messages from `__consumer_offsets` without consuming them.

(`kafka-go` either gives me a way to read from a single partition, or *consume*  messages from the entire topic)

So my question is, simply put: Is there a way, using any kafka library out there, to get consumer group offsets for all the groups for all the topics?

If not, is there a way to get the offset for a given topic and group id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get consumer group offsets for partition in Golang Kafka 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642689/how-to-get-consumer-group-offsets-for-partition-in-golang-kafka-10)

Comment: The answer in the question you point to gives a way to get the offset of the topic, not the consumer offset of the groups reading the topics

Comment: By the way, this library already does what you're asking (using Sarama) https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow